# Visual Studio does not shows project type when try to create a new project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

am trying to create a C# project. However, when i click File --> New Project,
I see  empty projects. It does not shows any selection option like C++, C# etc.
I have never seen this before.

I used to be able to select what type of project i want to create and then it creates the projecte. Now it says no items found. how i Can fix this issue. \

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its too an easy option to suggest but are you sure you have C++ and C# components of Visual Studio installed?